# Can I wear and pray with a t-shirt or watch that contains the logo of Ferrari

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, salat, practical-islam, sharia

Can I pray with the T-shirt or watch that contains the logo of Ferrari like the picture below?
It is said that if they don't have good details it won't be counted as imitating the creation of Allah(swt).[image]
And if possible please note evidences.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I want to specifically know whether wearing this logo is haram or no.